# Missing information in nested dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I created a dictionary from file using the code below:

```
Negdic={gene:{iso:exon.split(',')} for gene, iso, exon in zip(Genes, Isoforms, ExonPos)}
```

From these sample lists:

```
Genes = ['A2M', 'A2M', 'ACADS', 'ACADVL']

Isoforms = ['NM_000014', 'NM_000016', 'NM_000017', 'NM_000018']

ExonPos = ['9220303,9220778,9221335,9222340,9223083,9224954,9225248,9227155,9229351,9229941,9230296,9231839,9232234,9232689,9241795,9242497,9242951,9243796,9246060,9247568,9248134,9251202,9251976,9253739,9254042,9256834,9258831,9259086,9260119,9261916,9262462,9262909,9264754,9264972,9265955,9268359,', '76190031,76194085,76198328,76198537,76199212,76200475,76205664,76211490,76215103,76216135,76226806,76228376,', '121163570,121164828,121174788,121175158,121175639,121176082,121176335,121176622,121176942,121177098,', '7123149,7123440,7123782,7123922,7124084,7124242,7124856,7125270,7125495,7125985,7126451,7126962,7127131,7127286,7127464,7127639,7127798,7127960,7128127,7128275,']
```

However, I realized that after scrolling through the dictionary that the A2M with isofrom NM_000014 is missing. A2M NM_000014 should match with the first set of ExonPos numbers, A2M NM_000016 should match with the second set of ExonPos numbers and so on. What can I do to correct this? I missed this originally because of how large my dataset is which means that there will be many genes that have multiple isoforms and ExonPos.

How can I change this to were I get my output to look like this:

```
dict = {'gene': {'isoform1': [exonpos], 'isoform2': [exonpos2]}, 'gene2': {isofrom1..etc}
```

Comment: You'll only have missing information if one of the original lists is shorter than the other two - `zip` will ignore overflow data. Are you sure the lists are all the same length at the start?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have repeated keys so you will lose part of the data when zipping:

```
'A2M', 'A2M'
```

Python dicts cannot have duplicate keys so the `'A2M'` will have the last value matching the second occurrence.

To do what you want you would need something like the following to handle repeated keys:

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(list))

for k, iso, exon in zip(Genes, Isoforms, ExonPos):
    d[k][iso] = exon.split(",")

print(d["A2M"])

{'NM_000014': ['9220303', '9220778', '9221335', '9222340', '9223083', '9224954', '9225248', '9227155', '9229351', '9229941', '9230296', '9231839', '9232234', '9232689', '9241795', '9242497', '9242951', '9243796', '9246060', '9247568', '9248134', '9251202', '9251976', '9253739', '9254042', '9256834', '9258831', '9259086', '9260119', '9261916', '9262462', '9262909', '9264754', '9264972', '9265955', '9268359', ''],
 'NM_000016': ['76190031', '76194085', '76198328', '76198537', '76199212', '76200475', '76205664', '76211490', '76215103', '76216135', '76226806', '76228376', '']}
```

The defaultdict either adds the key the first time it encounters it or updates thereafter. Obviously if your iso's repeat you will encounter the same behaviour so that is something to be aware of.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I believe this has worked for me.

Comment: @christylynn002, no prob, glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the key of the dictionary should me unique.

In your case it is not so. So you miss all of the entries that use not unique keys.

Here:

```
Genes = ['A2M', 'A2M', 'ACADS', 'ACADVL']
```

`A2M` is repeating two times.